# Twitter bootstrap nav collapsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

This is how my code looks like but the problem is: **when I click on the collapsed button (the one with 4 horizontal lines), it won't open on the 1st click, but only on the second click.** 1st click does nothing and 2nd opens it quickly, than quickly closes it, than reopens it again. Why is that and how to fix it?

```
 22     <!-- BOOTSTRAP NAVBAR -->
 23     <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
 24       <div class="navbar-inner">        
 25         <div class="container">
 26 
 27           <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">                                                   
 28             <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
 29             <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
 30             <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
 31             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 32           </a>
 33     
 34           <%= link_to 'Synergy', root_path, :class => 'brand' %>                                                                          
 35 
 36           <div class="nav-collapse">                                                                                            
 37 
 38             <% if current_user %>                                                                                                         
 39 
 40               <ul class="nav">
 41                 <li><%= link_to 'My projects', projects_path %></li>
 42                 <li><%= link_to current_user.name, '#' %></li>
 43                 <li><%= link_to 'Log out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>
 44               </ul>        
 45 
 46             <% else %>     
 47 
 48               <ul class="nav">
 49                 <li><%= link_to 'Sign in', new_user_session_path %></li>
 50                 <li><%= link_to 'Sign up!', new_user_registration_path %></li>
 51               </ul>        
 52 
 53             <% end %>      
 54 
 55           </div>           
 56 
 57         </div>             
 58       </div>               
 59     </div>
 60     <!-- BOOTSTRAP NAVBAR -->
```

EDIT: this is my application.js file:

```
 13 //= require jquery
 14 //= require jquery_ujs
 15 //= require jquery-ui
 16 //= require twitter/bootstrap
 17 //= require_tree .
```

Comment: Why are you nesting your nav collapse inside another container? only one is needed, `<div class="container nav-collapse">` remove the `container` class from this div, also, in what order is your js loading?

Comment: thanks. I have edited the question as I understood you to fix my divs. Was this what you had in mind? Also, my JS load at the end of the file, right above the </body> tag, and I have only this line in there > <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>. Should I rearange something?

Comment: the other that which the js loads matter, since the dropdown plugin is required for this feature and as such should be loaded after the jquery plugin. So, jQuery first > bootstrap.js second - or if you're including the individual plugins it goes transition.js plugin first then the dropdown plugin.

Comment: I don't fully understand, can you please, write those down. Also, I am using twitter-bootstrap gem. Does that matter at all?

Comment: So, the order that the js needs to load in is jquery first, as always, then the bootstrap plugins. The reason being is that since the bootstrap plugins are jquery plugins, they need to load "after" jquery has loaded, otherwise you will get results like the ones you're seeing now. Bootstrap plugins load first, jquery second, you click on an element that requires jquery to load, it doesn't work on the first try though it gets triggered, on the second try it works. Don't know much about the gem but that should be the order in your final markup once the page is loaded so just view the source.

Comment: I added in the question my application.js file in wich you can see the order I load js. It still doesn't work properly... any other ideas?

Comment: none at all, the order of your js looks fine so there must be something else. Can you post a link to your site?

Comment: Are you sure your CSS/JS manifests aren't double-including some of the JS files for bootstrap?  Since you're using rails I'd recommend this gem: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.  Also, I'd recommend taking a look at the simple working example here: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/starter-template.html

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are double loading some of the JS files. It can be easy to forget where the files are loading in an environment like Ruby or Grails.

Try including the call to Jquery in the page script and place an inline script directly after the call. An example would be this:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-carousel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-transition.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel();
  });
</script>
```

After you add this script check the web console in Firebug or another developer tool. You should see if jQuery is loading properly or multiple times. Let me know if that solves the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, something similar to this was happening because I had precompiled my assets previously for production, and the dev and prod js assets were both running.

`rake assets:clean` (rails3) / `rake assets:clobber` (rails4) fixed this.